# Access to application folder iOS

Tags: ios

Some applications like iFunBox and iPhone Folders are able to access the applications folders on the iOS device. Could someone explain why these applications have this possibility and App store applications don't?

Comment: I think you can't access other application folder in apple's sanboxing environment in case of ios.

Comment: "You can't" is not true, furthermore this was not the question.

Comment: @H2CO3 But according to apple's policies I think they will reject the app if you use the private apis.

Comment: OP is not talking about iOS apps. He's talking about desktop apps that access iOS' filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Because they aren't restricted by the sandbox.

iOS apps are put in their separate sandbox ("chroot jail") and they can't really access anything outside of that particular folder.

However, desktop applications can use Apple's private MobileDevice framework (it's a C API) to access any folders on the device, this is how iTunes installs applications, songs, developer disk images, etc.

Some unofficial documentation of this framework can be found [here](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=MobileDevice_Library).